# Django REST View FileHandling

Tags: django-rest-framework

Using Django REST, post request to my API View :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    serializer = DocumentSerializer(data=request.data)

    try:

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        new_document = Documents.objects.create(
            TipoDoc = serializer.data.get("TipoDoc"),
            DataInsert = serializer.data.get("DataInsert"),
            DataInizio = serializer.data.get("DataInizio"),
            DataFine = serializer.data.get("DataFine"),
            CompanyID = serializer.data.get("CompanyID"),
            Doc = serializer.validated_data.get("Doc").read()
        )

    Except : blablabla
```

ERROR :

'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'Doc'
Internal Server Error: /docs/
[27/Feb/2024 07:52:26] "POST /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 500 108

DATA PASSED:

blablabla
'Doc': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: MyTestFile.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>

MODEL :

class Documents(models.Model):

```
class Meta:
    db_table = "documents"

DocID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
TipoDoc = models.TextField()
DataInsert = models.TextField()
DataInizio = models.TextField()
DataFine = models.TextField()
CompanyID = models.TextField()
Doc = models.BinaryField()
```

Can't understand why gives me this type of error. My PDF file is good, there is maybe some issue with the function create?

Tried to modify how i validated data,
tried to modify the order
tried to set the database exactly as the model

Comment: its better to use Filefield in models

Answer (score 0):

```
serializer.validated_data.get("Doc").read()
```

You have to remove this and explicitly add the line in the object creation, like this

```
     Cart.objects.create(
       user=serializer.validated_data['user'],
       name=serializer.validated_data['name'],
       price=serializer.validated_data['price'],
       doc=request.data.get('doc').read()
     )
```

[image]